# scrape url from a page using visitor ip

Tags: php, curl, scrape

i make get_file_contents for a video url from a website with this code:

```
<?php $get = file_get_contents("https://vidhd.net/embed-bc3c7z8e8pmt.html");
    $regex = '/(https|http)[^"]*(?=",label)/';
    if (preg_match_all($regex, $get, $allurlget)){
     foreach($allurlget[0] as $getlist) {
          $TakeJsonToList[] = $getlist;}
           if (count($TakeJsonToList) == 3){
               $Makejson =  array ('p720' => $TakeJsonToList[0],
                                    'p480' => $TakeJsonToList[1],
                                    'p360' => $TakeJsonToList[2]);
          }else if (count($TakeJsonToList) == 2){
               $Makejson =  array ('p720' => $TakeJsonToList[0],
                                    'p480' => $TakeJsonToList[1]);
          }else{
               $Makejson =  array ('p720' => $TakeJsonToList[0]);
          }
    echo json_encode($Makejson);}
        else{
            $filenotfound = 'Url Not Found';
            $error = json_encode(array('error'=> $filenotfound));
        echo ($error);
    }
```

now i take output as json Like this :

```
{"p720":"https:\/\/s4.vidhd.net\/kmxssvaapjumwmesrlvuyy72hjmxnedreq2ahr5kil6qqt373orzkuun4ccq\/v.mp4","p480":"https:\/\/s4.vidhd.net\/kmxssvaapjumwmesrlvuyy72hjmxnedreq2ahr5kiriqqt373or7r273xqrq\/v.mp4"}
```

but when i make the request the another web "Vidhd"
        make the video url with my website ip .
        so when i play the video i get Wrong ip !! yes sure because the url ip is with my website ip not with my computer ip
        What i need ?
        i need to make the request with the visitor ip not server ip Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

from vidhd.net's perspective, the ip used to fetch the video (through the direct video file url) must be the same ip that requested the video. so either stream the video directly from php (eg, with readfile()), or fetch the video url directly from the vistor's ip (eg, via javascript/XMLHttpRequest)

the first method has the downside of using more bandwidth, as the entire video has to be downloaded to your server and served to the client, making your server's bandwidth usage 2*size of the movie. the downside of the second method is that you'll probably run into [CORS restrictions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) doing it from javascript, unless vidhd explicitly allows CORS requests via the [CORS-Allow headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers), and according to curl, they do not:

```
$ curl -I https://vidhd.net/embed-bc3c7z8e8pmt.html
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 31 May 2018 13:25:56 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Expires: Wed, 30 May 2018 13:25:56 GMT
X-frame-options: 1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

although you might be able to just use an iframe, unless they block iframes, who knows.